# change class of div server-side after user input

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, forms

I'm working on a project where users can choose squares of a big field and "book" them.
The grid is just a html table with each  having a unique id (1,2,3...).
similar to this example: http://jsfiddle.net/MvFx9/
`$`
Now after they submit a simple form, the chosen squares turn yellow. i do this with javascript, search all elements by its id and change their class. And it works perfect.

What i want to do now is to change the class of each chosen element server-side. So that when a new user loads the page, he sees yellow squares, which are already booked by other users.

But i dont know how to do it, i guess its not possible with javascript, so i tried it with php. Is there a equivalent getelementbyid function and how can i change the class of each element?

Please give me an advice, thanks.

Comment: How are you generating your table?

Comment: I generated it with javascript and then copy pasted it to my index.php file. So its hard coded now.

Answer (score 1):

In some way, you will need to save which squares have been booked by others

**The general idea :**

1) Whenever a user click on a square, you save the id in a table in the database. You can use a form (it will reload the page) or if you want it cleaner, you perform an AJAX call.

2) When displaying the page, you retrieve the id that have been saved and set the class "already_booked" for them dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a database to know which spots are booked.Anything else will take you a long while to do and won't be as efficient.

Answer (score -1):

```
DOMDocument::getElementById('element_id')
```

Use the PHP DOMDocument class to do this.

http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementbyid.php

**Edit:** didn't fully read the question.

http://docs.php.net/manual/en/domelement.setattribute.php

```
setAttribute("class", "already_booked");
```